# How to add sqrt in WPF calculator c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new in c#! can anyone help me how to add a sqrt button in calculator which has been created in WPF. The code that I pasted here works fine, but I have to add another button which should be square root, but I don't know how to do it. Please can anyone help me with that I would really appreciate

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyCalculatorv1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // all button 0 to 9 go here. 
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button) sender;
            tb.Text += b.Content.ToString();
        }

        // equal button goes here
        private void Result_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                result();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                tb.Text = "Error!";
            }
        }

        private void result()
        {
            String op;
            int iOp = 0;
            if (tb.Text.Contains("+"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("+");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("-"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("-");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("*"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("*");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("/"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("/");
            }
            else
            {
                //error
            }

            op = tb.Text.Substring(iOp, 1);
            double op1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(0, iOp));
            double op2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(iOp + 1, tb.Text.Length - iOp - 1));

            if (op == "+")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 + op2);
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 - op2);
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 * op2);
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 / op2);
            }
        }

        private void Off_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Del_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb.Text = "";
        }

        private void R_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                tb.Text = tb.Text.Substring(0, tb.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }

        private void about(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("simple calculator");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the code throws an error? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on editing this into better shape if no one has a quick answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math.Sqrt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="&#8730;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
            Click="OnSquareRootClick"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="240,10,0,0" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
 private void OnSquareRootClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double number;
        var isDouble = double.TryParse(this.txtNumber.Text, out number);
        if (isDouble)
        {
            this.txtResult.Text =
                string.Format(
                    "{0}{1} = {2}", 
                    "\u221A", 
                    this.txtNumber.Text, 
                    Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(number), 2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works only for the numbers 9,4 and 1 when i click on the other numbers it show only the = sign it doesn't show any result! Should I do anything else beside these commands that you gave me? please i need further help, thank you

Comment: you will need to debug, ensure the tb.Text is number because if it is not number my code will not do anything. I updated to include round

Comment: Updated my answer to make it clear, tested on sample project. You need to change it base on your needs